# Pyrebase Raspberry Pi Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, raspberry-pi, iot

I'm using this code for on/off led using raspberry pi 3 and firebase for raspberry pi 3 but getting error. I'm new on python. So what is this error means and how to solve this error?

```
#import Libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pyrebase

#Firebase Configuration
config = {
  "apiKey": "xxxxx",
  "authDomain": "xxxxx",
  "databaseURL": "xxxxx",
  "storageBucket": "xxxxx"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

#GPIO Setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

#Firebase Database Intialization
db = firebase.database()

#While loop to run until user kills program
while(True):
    #Get value of LED 
    led = db.child("led").get()

    #Sort through children of LED(we only have one)
    for user in led.each():
        #Check value of child(which is 'state')
        if(user.val() == "OFF"):
            #If value is off, turn LED off
            GPIO.output(18, False)
        else:
            #If value is not off(implies it's on), turn LED on
            GPIO.output(18, True)

        #0.1 Second Delay
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The error is;

```
Traceback (most recent call last);
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/led.py", line 30, in <module>
  for user in led.each():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: A qiuck guess is that `db.child("led")` is not getting any data. Are you sure that: 1) data exists in that location, 2) the data is readably by your Python code, and 3) it has multiple values, so it can be looped over?